# NaN is not recognized in pandas after np.where clause. Why? Or is it a bug?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

NaN is not recognized in pandas after np.where clause. Why? Or is it a bug?

The last line of this code should be "True"

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: import numpy as np   
In [3]: a=pd.Series([1,np.nan])    
In [4]: b=pd.DataFrame(["a","b"])  
In [5]: b["1"]=np.where(
            a.isnull(),
            np.nan,
            "Hello"
        )   
In [6]: b
Out[6]:
   0      1
0  a  Hello
1  b    nan    
In [7]: b[1].isnull()
Out[7]:
0    False
1    False
Name: 1, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can see why if you look at the result of the `where`:

```
>>> np.where(a.isnull(), np.nan, "Hello")
array([u'Hello', u'nan'], 
      dtype='<U32')
```

Because your other value is a string, `where` converts your `NaN` to a string as well and gives you a string-dtyped result.  (The exact dtype you get may different depending on your platform and/or Python version.)  So you don't actually have a NaN in your result at all, you just have the string `"nan"`.

If you want to do this type of mapping (in particular, mapping that changes dtypes) in pandas, it's usually better to use pandas constructs like `.map` and avoid dropping into numpy, because as you saw, numpy tends to do unhelpful things when it has to resolve conflicting types.  Here's an example of how to do it all in pandas:

```
>>> b["X"] = a.isnull().map({True: np.nan, False: "Hello"})
>>> b
   0      X
0  a  Hello
1  b    NaN
>>> b.X.isnull()
0    False
1     True
Name: X, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Is there a pandas np.where function that allows to deal with such things? Or is there another way to rewrite it so that it works?